# Setting Integer, Double and String columnTypes for csvjdbc table

Tags: sql, csv, jdbc

I am trying to select different fields from a csv file with the [csvjdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) driver. I got a csv-table like:

```
id        departmentcode     fte
223356    DS3G5530DK         1.0
234335    ES4K44343L         0.8
435331    GS2K54534P         1.0
...
```

I want to import the columns as Integer, String and Double, so I made a Java.Util.Properties object and added the column types:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("columnTypes", "Integer,String,Double");
```

After that I make a connection with the properties object and query the csv:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:" +getPath()+"/temp/", props);
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, departmentcode, fte FROM tempCSV WHERE ...")

while (results.next()) {
    ...
    System.out.println( results.getInt("id") );
    System.out.println( results.getString("departmentcode") );
    System.out.println( results.getDouble("fte") );
    ...
}
```

But when I select from my result the DEPARTMENT-CODE, it is always a double (0.0). For both `id` and `fte` it goes as expected (as `id` is a int and `fte` a double). Is something wrong with my properties object?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and error I think I do understand the problem. The columnTypes seems to behave strange. First every column is parsed in the last columnType (for me it would be `Double`). After parsing to that columnType, the data is tranformed into given type (for me that would be either `Integer`, `String` or `Double`).

And that's where it goes wrong: parsing a String Object to Double will yield a 0.0. I fixed it by removing the whole columnType property and adding single quotes in my sql where statement.

Answer (score 0):

What is the separator between values on each line of your CSV file?  The default in CsvJdbc is a comma.  You can set a different separator as a database property.  For example,

```
props.put("separator", "|");
```

Or maybe your file has fixed width columns on each line?  In that case, you can set the `fixedWidths` database property to define the width of each column.

Answer (score 0):

You need add something like this to your properties:

```
props.put("fixedWidths", "1-10,11-30,31-32");
```

(Specify the column start and end points)